# Linq to XML navigation problem

Tags: xml, linq

I know this should be simple but I am having a difficult time navigating the following XML with LINQ to XML (I think the `<soapenv:Body>` is messing me up) All I need to do at this point is count the number of `<addressData>` elements. Eventually I will need to read the values of each element within each `<addressData>` element.

XML:

```
<soapenv:Body>
<getAddrResponse xmlns="http://urlhere.com/v1">
    <AddrResponse>
        <requestorId>123456</requestorId>
        <address>
            <addressCount>3</addressCount>
            <addressData>
                <addressLine1>123 MAIN ST</addressLine1>
                <cityName>HOLLYWOOD</cityName>
                <stateCode>CA</stateCode>
                <zipCode>90028</zipCode>
                <zipPlus4Code>1234</zipPlus4Code>
            </addressData>
            <addressData>
                <addressLine1>456 MAIN ST</addressLine1>
                <cityName>HOLLYWOOD</cityName>
                <stateCode>CA</stateCode>
                <zipCode>90028</zipCode>
                <zipPlus4Code>1234</zipPlus4Code>
            </addressData>
            <addressData>
                <addressLine1>789 MAIN ST</addressLine1>
                <cityName>HOLLYWOOD</cityName>
                <stateCode>CA</stateCode>
                <zipCode>90028</zipCode>
                <zipPlus4Code>1234</zipPlus4Code>
            </addressData>
        </address>
    </AddrResponse>
</getAddrResponse>
</soapenv:Body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XML is currently illegal: your outer namespace is not defined. So assuming your XML is really like

```
<soapenv:Body xmlns:soapenv="foo.com">
 ...
```

You can get the `addressData` count like this:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
XNamespace someNamespace = "http://urlhere.com/v1";
int addressCount = doc.Descendants(someNamespace + "addressData").Count();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to take namespaces and namespace prefixes into account, including declaring `soapenv`:

```
var xml =  "<soapenv:Body xmlns:soapenv=\""
          +"http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope\">...</soapenv:Body>";
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
XNamespace ns = "http://urlhere.com/v1";

var addressDatas = doc.Root.Descendants(ns+"addressData");

var count = addressDatas.Count();

var firstAddressLine = addressDatas.First().Element(ns+"addressLine1").Value;
```

Comment: Thx. I saw the other response first and it worked. Looks like your approach will work too. It was the namespace issue that was throwing me off.